# change content of a sql column to all the same

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

i have a column named (status) in table name oc_product

This column conects to my product to be 1= actif  0=inactif

now i want my column in my sql database to be all at 0 so al will be inactif
so is thare a code to alter all the content in the column (status) so all in that column must be 0

thanks

Comment: Yes.  It is called `update`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
     oc_product
SET
     status = 0
--it feels dirty not putting a WHERE clause here, but this is the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE oc_product SET status = 0`

That should do the trick. Since there is no WHERE clause, the `status` values of all records in `oc_product` will be set to 0.

EDIT: you may need to escape `status` like `[status]`. I'm not so used to mysql syntax details, so maybe status is a keyword and needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE oc_product SET status = 0;
```

the UPDATE statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with new values